# findAndModify Error in mongodb - nodejs - error code 17287

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, findandmodify

I am getting following error :

> MongoError: exception: nextSafe(): { $err: "Can't canonicalize query:
>   B adValue bad sort specification", code: 17287 }

```
functions.getNextIndex = function(callback){

    db.collection('counters').findAndModify(
            {_id:'productId'},
            {$inc: {sequence_value:1}},

            function(err,data){
                if(!err)
                    callback(data);
                else
                    callback(err);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are missing the "sort" argument in your query.

Try something like:

```
db.collection('counters').findAndModify(
    {_id:'productId'},
    {_id:'descending'},
    {$inc: {sequence_value:1}},

    function(err,data){
        if(!err)
            callback(data);
        else
            callback(err);
});
```

See more here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: Works for me too, but only if I specify one of the fields other than _id for some reason?