# nodejs mongodb find modify and return new. Can't canonicalize query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My question is related to this

[findAndModify Error in mongodb - nodejs - error code 17287](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771052/findandmodify-error-in-mongodb-nodejs-error-code-17287)

But the solution hasn't worked (i tried specify the order but i get the same error) I think it might be something along the lines of the index I am using `example` instead of `_id` (`_id` is a field in this collection I just don't want to search by `_id` in this case) not sure at all...

The Error:

```
{ [MongoError: exception: nextSafe(): { $err: "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification", code: 17287 }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'exception: nextSafe(): { $err: "Can\'t canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification", code: 17287 }',
  errmsg: 'exception: nextSafe(): { $err: "Can\'t canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification", code: 17287 }',
  code: 13106,
  ok: 0 }
```

This is my code, it should find and modify (and return using new:true) the first instance of a document that has the field `example` equal to minus one.

```
db.collection('documents').findAndModify({example:-1},{$set:{example:0}},{new:true},function(err,result){
    console.dir(err||result);
    });
```

But all it does is error like it hates my face!

Here is a document:

```
{'_id':0,'example':-1}
```

My id field is custom numerical Where I ensure the _id is always unique (For my purposes I cannot change the _id to standard mongodb way.)

Comment: Could you post a sample document?

Comment: Sample document added to the end of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was painful to get this to work as the node docs end abruptly and then you are left guessing on how the code structure should be on what would/could of just been a standard structure but isn't! I have wasted a day thanks to the devs undocumented methods.

Here is the working code

```
db.collection('documents').findAndModify({'example':{$eq:-1}},[['example',1]],{$set:{'example':-1}},{'new':true},function(err,result){
    console.dir(err||result);
    });
```

I am not sure I really like writing code like this ether. I might look for another node module for this as the query above looks disgusting!

Would be greate if I could find something that looks as simple as this:

```
db.collection('documents').findModifyReturn('find:example==-1;order:asc;set:example=0;',function(e,r){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`$eq`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) operator.

```
db.collection('documents').findAndModify({example: {$eq: -1}}, {'example', 'ascending'},{$set:{example:0}},{new:true},function(err,result){
    console.dir(err||result);
    });
```

Comment: Try now. It requires all three parameters before the callback.

Comment: Thanks, you have a typo `{'example', 'ascending'}` should be  `{'example': 'ascending'}` and no it still doesn't work (has same error)